# How to push another key and value to the jsondata at a specific position

Tags: jquery

I have a existing json as shown below .

```
{
    "vendors": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "Minerva Coffee Shop",
                "data": {
                    "orderinfo": [
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "986000454",
                        },
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "986600054",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i want to push another key and value to the above jsondata under the  orderinfo array , so  that my jsondata have to be like this.

```
{
    "vendors": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "Minerva Coffee Shop",
                "data": {
                    "orderinfo": [
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "986000454",
                            "comments": "This is Tasty" 
                        },
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "986600054",
                          "comments": "This is Tasty" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried as shown in this fiddle , but its being inserted at the end .

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/2/

Could you please let me know how to do this , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the updated code does what you need:

```js
var json = {
    "vendors": {
        "T1": [
            {
                "name": "Minerva Coffee Shop",
                "data": {
                    "orderinfo": [
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "986000454"
                        },
                        {
                            "contact_phone_no": "986600054"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

var comments = 'This is tasty' ;


json.vendors.T1[0].data.orderinfo[0].comments = comments ;
json.vendors.T1[0].data.orderinfo[1].comments = comments ;

alert(JSON.stringify(json))
```

Comment: Thank you very much , but the problem is that ,the length of orderinfo array is dynamic .